# Javascript - Decorator pattern on prototype dont work

Tags: javascript, decorator

I am trying to learn decorator pattern in js. Could you explain me, why `ComputerDecorator` does not have `cost()` method? This is my code:

```
function Computer(){
  this._cost = 3000;
}

Computer.prototype.cost = function(){
  return this._cost;
}

function ComputerDecorator(computer){
    Computer.call(this);
    this.computer = computer;
}

ComputerDecorator.prototype = Object.create(Computer.prototype);
ComputerDecorator.prototype.cost = function(){
  return this._cost  + this.computer.cost();
};

function MacAir(computer){
  ComputerDecorator.call(this, computer);
  this._cost = 2500;
}

var mac = new Computer();
mac = new MacAir(mac);
console.log(mac)
```

And here is console log:

```
[object Object] {
  _cost: 2500,
  computer: [object Object] {
    _cost: 3000,
    cost: function (){
    return this._cost;
    }
  }
}
```

I will appreciate every help. Thanks!

Comment: You are making a public `_cost` instance property (because you used `this._cost`) and a public inherited `cost` method. To truly encapsulate the data, `this._cost`, should be `var _cost`. Otherwise, someone could just bypass your method and simply get the `_cost` property value.

Answer (score 0):

`MacAir` is not prototype-linked with `ComputerDecorator`. You are just calling `ComputerDecorator` constructor inside `MacAir`constructor. In order to have `cost()` method in `MacAir`, you need to link `MacAir` with `ComputerDecorator` prototype, like so:

```js
function Computer(){
  this._cost = 3000;
}

Computer.prototype.cost = function(){
  return this._cost;
}

function ComputerDecorator(computer){
    Computer.call(this);
    this.computer = computer;
}

ComputerDecorator.prototype = Object.create(Computer.prototype);
ComputerDecorator.prototype.cost = function(){
  return this._cost  + this.computer.cost();
};

function MacAir(computer){
  ComputerDecorator.call(this, computer);
  this._cost = 2500;
}
MacAir.prototype = Object.create(ComputerDecorator.prototype);

var mac = new Computer();
mac = new MacAir(mac);
console.log(mac)
```

Comment: Exactly. I forget about linking MacAir with ComputerDecorator.
Thank you very much. (;